# variable scope in Java

Tags: java, scope

How to let variable `srcAdd1` and `dstAdd1` also can be used outside the `if {}`? variable `srcAdd1` and `dstAdd1` can only be declared in `IPPacket`.

```
packet1 = jpcap.getPacket();

if (packet1 instanceof IPPacket) {
  IPPacket ipp1 = (IPPacket)packet1;
  InetAddress srcAdd1 = ipp1.src_ip;
  InetAddress dstAdd1 = ipp1.dst_ip;

  if (ipp1 instanceof TCPPacket) {
    TCPPacket tcp1 = (TCPPacket)ipp1;
    int dstPort1 = tcp1.dst_port;

    if (dstPort1 == 135) {
      System.out.println(srcAdd1 +" "+  dstAdd1 +" "+ dstPort1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Err, declare them in the outer scope? This is really not a networking question let alone a JPcap question, just a very basic, beginner-level, Java programming question.

Answer (score 1):

It is a local variable and is limited to the {} scope.

From the [**JLS**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.4.2)

> The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.2) is the
>   rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its
>   own initializer (§14.4) and including any further declarators to the
>   right in the local variable declaration statement.

If you want it to be visible outside the scope, consider making it a field in your class.

Answer (score 1):

```
packet1 = jpcap.getPacket();
InetAddress srcAdd1 = null;
InetAddress dstAdd1 = null;

if (packet1 instanceof IPPacket) {
  IPPacket ipp1 = (IPPacket)packet1;
  srcAdd1 = ipp1.src_ip;
  dstAdd1 = ipp1.dst_ip;

  if (ipp1 instanceof TCPPacket) {
    TCPPacket tcp1 = (TCPPacket)ipp1;
    int dstPort1 = tcp1.dst_port;

    if (dstPort1 == 135) {
      System.out.println(srcAdd1 +" "+  dstAdd1 +" "+ dstPort1);
    }
  }
}

// later

// this condition is true only if packet1 is an instance of IPPacket
if(srcAdd1 != null && dstAdd1 != null) {
    // do stuff with srcAdd1 and dstAdd1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `Declaring` a variable **inside a block**, will restrict its scope within that block.

**2.** `Declaring` a variable **within the Class scope**, will have **accessibility throughout the class.**

**3.** Declare `srcAdd1`, and `dstAdd1` at **class scope**.

**Example:**

```
public class Test{
  InetAddress srcAdd1;
  InetAddress dstAdd1;

public void go(){

  // Your code................

  srcAdd1 = ipp1.src_ip;
  dstAdd1 = ipp1.dst_ip;

 // Your code................

  }
}
```